# Database design - Subclass relation model

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

I'm a bit confused on how should I design my tables for a this example SQL database.

I've got `Customer` entities. Customers can own many `Pet` entities. Every Pet must have its own `MedicalHistory`. But some of the Pets are female so they have a `FemaleMedicalHistory`. At last, every FemaleMedicalHistory can have many `Birth` records.

So `FemaleMedicalHistory` seems to be a subclass of `MedicalHistory`, containing the same fields plus something that points to the `Birth` table. Is this right?

How would you model these relations to tables? Should the `MedicalHistory` & `FemaleMedicalHistory` tables share the same primary key (eg. mid)?

**Edit:**

This was what I had in mind, but I'm not sure it fits:
[image]

Comment: Homework? Why don't you show us your current idea how to solve it.

Comment: @BjoernRennhak No, its the database relations for a project app I'm currently trying to develop. I uploaded my first schema attempt, but for some reason it doesnt seem fit. What do you think?

Comment: anyone? i thought that was simple and i was just missing something..

Comment: @LePhleg: The 'medical_history' is a very bad idea on its own, and this led you to defining the 'medical_history_female' table. Better to have a table with only a few fields - mid, pid, curdate, treatment_type and details - but with many rows. Each row would be a record of treatment for each pet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@LePhleg: The 'medical_history' is a very bad idea on its own, and this led you to defining the 'medical_history_female' table. Better to have a table with only a few fields - mid, pid, curdate, treatment_type and details - but with many rows. Each row would be a record of treatment for each pet. This structure obviates the need for both 'medical_history_female' and 'births' tables: a birth is an event which would be stored in the (new) medical history.

So for one animal (let's say a female dog), there could be several events in the medical_history table - worming, treating a broken leg, birth, birth, spaying, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I follow KISS principle so I would design it as  1:many between Pet and Birth records - Birth table contains information about Pet, not the Medical History does it? Also, what is "Birth"? I would have more meaningful names for tables and its attributes - IMHO it's so 20th century to try to save every character in table/attribute names.